# Template specialization for type traits where the type change depending on conditional

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization, type-traits

Assume we have a given class `ABC` that is templated with `K` and `V`:

```cpp
template <typename K, typename V>
using ABC = AnotherClass<K, V>
```

I know that it is possible to implement type traits that check if a template `T` is of the given class `ABC`, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct is_class_abc : std::false_type {};

template <typename K, typename V>
struct is_class_abc<ABC<K, V>> : std::true_type {};
```

Assume we change the `ABC` definition to be `AnotherClass` with types that change depending on `K` and `V`:

```cpp
template <typename K, typename V>
using ABC = AnotherClass<typename std::conditional<
      CONDITION, SOMETHING, SOMETHIN_ELSE>::type, ... >
```

The condition, something and something_else all depend and rely on K-V.

I get this compile error:

> Class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
>
> Non-deducible template parameter 'K'

Same for `V`.

Any idea if it is possible to do this? If so, how do I make it work?

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: *"class ABC"* - Not a class. Not even a class template. Aliases behave somewhat differently.

Comment: Do `CONDITION`, `SOMETHING`, and `SOMETHIN_ELSE` ever use `K` and `V`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. Does it change anything?

Comment: Can we see an example of real code that produces this error message?  Diagnosing code we can't see is unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial specialization will not only check if the passed type is of the form `ABC<K,V>` but it also will try/need to deduce `K` and `V`. Now let's look at how this would work. Assume we pass the type trait should check `ABC<K, V>`. Since `ABC` is only a type alias, the actual type passed to this type trait will actually be of the form `AnotherClass<K',V'>` where `K'` and `V'` are some modification of `K` and `V`.

Now the type trait would need to deduce `K` and `V` back from `K'` and `V'`, this is really necessary since it is possible that there are no such `K` and `V`. But since you use the `std::conditional<...>::type`, it is not transparent to the compiler what is going on there. This is called a non-deduced context. Basically, there some easy cases where we can deduce in the backwards direction (e.g. if you habe `ABC = AnotherClass<const K, V>`). In many cases (such as when you use a typedef inside another type, like here) that is to complicated/not possible.

This is not always intuitive and sometimes baffling, such as here:

```
template<class>
struct is_const : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_const<const T> : std::true_type {}; // This works

template<class T>
struct is_const<typename add_const<T>::type> : std::true_type {}; // This does NOT work
```

The second specialization also only adds a const such as `const T` does, but this is hidden (aka in a non-deduced context) and hence we cannot deduce `T`.

Comment: Thanks! tl;dr: so it is not possible, right?

Comment: Not possible. Depending on what you are doing there is maybe a work around but not in this generality.